# Allure 2 is not showing ignored tests

Tags: allure

I'm using allure2+testng+gradle and I can generate allure report similar with this https://github.com/sskorol/allure2-testng-report. The problem is that I can't see any ignored by TestNG tests. I.e. I have 2 tests:

```
@Test
@Story("Test 1")
public void test1() {

}


@Test(enabled = false)
@Story("Test 2")
public void test2() {

}
```

How to display in allure report that Test2 is ignored ?

Answer (score 0):

resolved by adding allure-testng-adaptor